# SQLCMD within a VBS

Tags: vbscript, sqlcmd

I am trying to write a section into a script which attaches a DB via SQLCMD.

If I run this from a CMD line/batch file it attaches the DB successfully:

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P RubbishPassword -S (local) -Q "sp_attach_db 'MyDBInstance','D:\AFolder\MyDB.mdf','D:\MyDBInstance\MyDB_log.ldf'"
```

However if I run it within a VBS by doing the below it doesn't error but doesn't attach the DB.

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "sqlcmd -U sa -P RubbishPassword -S (local) -Q ""sp_attach_db 'MyDBInstance','D:\AFolder\MyDB.mdf','D:\MyDBInstance\MyDB_log.ldf'"
```

Any ideas on why and/or a better way of passing a SQLCMD via VBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing double quotes for `-Q` option is missing in your command.

> objShell.Run "sqlcmd -U sa -P RubbishPassword -S (local) -Q
>   ""sp_attach_db
>   'MyDBInstance','D:\AFolder\MyDB.mdf','D:\MyDBInstance\MyDB_log.ldf'`""`"

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug your command with wscript.echo or a MsgBox like this :

```
Command = "sqlcmd -U sa -P *** -S (local) -Q "& DblQuote("sp_attach_db 'Aztec','D:\Aztecdata\Aztec.mdf','D:\Aztecdata\Aztec_log.ldf'")
wscript.echo Command

'***********************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***********************************************************************
```